# How to get data from HTML checkbox in Node-red?

Tags: html, node.js, node-red

[image]

I'm trying to get data from checkbox alert in Node-red. Inside the template node,

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>테스트</title>
<script>
window.onload = function(){
    for(var i = 0; i < document.getElementsByTagName('input').length; i++){
        if(document.getElementsByTagName('input')[i].getAttribute('type') == 'checkbox'){
            document.getElementsByTagName('input')[i].checked = true;
        }
    }
};
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <label>test<input type="checkbox" /></label>
    <label>test2<input type="checkbox" /></label>
    <label>test3</label><input type="checkbox" /></label>
    <label>test4<input type="checkbox" /></label>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my Code in template node. If i inject the node, notification appears.
[image]

Even i press Ok/Cancel, nothing happened.The only payload that i can see is 
this one which i first inject node, raw template code appears.

[image]

What i want to do is, ***I want individual output among those checkboxes.***
For example, if i check 'test1', I wanna make msg.payload="test1" or any number, string etc.
If i check 'test2', 'test3' , 'test4' same. Anyone knows about this? Tnx for reading.
Regards.

Comment: You don't, the alert node doesn't work that way

Comment: @hardillb Should i find other way to handle it?